# MorseCode Decoder Having trouble using hashing and counting whitespace C++

Tags: c++

I have a program I have to write using hashing which I am not familiar with and do not really understand. Right now I am having trouble counting the whitespace between the words I am reading in if it is a letter it is separated by one space and once the code makes a word it is separated by two spaces when it is being read in. My decode function works fine but I don't know how to count the spaces. Here is one thing I have tried but it doesn't work any help would be great.

```
string tmp;
MORSE TABLE[20];
int j = 0, f = 0, k = 0;
char x;
while(!infile.eof())
{
    infile >> tmp;
    infile.get(x);
     if(x == ' ') //check if x is a space
     {
       infile.get(x); //read next character
       if(x == ' ') //check and see if next char is a space
        {
          TABLE[k].insert(' '); //insert space into char array for printing
        }
      }

   if(j >= f) //if true create new object
     { 
         k++; f+=100; 
     }  

    TABLE[k].decode(tmp);//pass in string to decode
    j++;
}//end while loop
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am not a very advanced C++ person just a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Streams by default skip whitespace, which you can control with a [flag](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/flags/). However, I'd suggest a line-based approach to you, otherwise you also need to handle newlines:

```
string line;
while(getline(infile, line))
{ ...use line...  }
```

BTW:

- The `while(!in.eof())` does not guarantee you that you can read from the stream. Try to read and check for success instead. The above does that already.
- It would help if you provided the exact input and the exact expected output. Start off with a stringstream, initialized with the file content, and then read a single element from it. Provide that code here for further help, after stripping anything that is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Great help I ended up using peek() for the second if statement and that turned out to do just what I needed. But thanks for the response.